# Implementation of addall(int i, Collection<? extends T> c) )

Tags: java, data-structures, performance

I wrote this code to implement addAll() function in a BulkArrayDeque that extends an arrayDeque. But when I tested it on a server I got this error: BulkArrayDeque contains incorrect values after using addAll.

Can someone please tell me what i did wrong in the addAll() function. The addAll() function is suppose to add all the elements from the collection starting at i, efficiently. Or is there another way to do it. Someone, please?

```
public class BulkArrayDeque<T> extends ArrayDeque<T> {
  public BulkArrayDeque(Class<T> clazz) {
    super(clazz);
  }


public boolean addAll(int i, Collection<? extends T> c) {

    n=n+c.size();
    for (T x : c){

        if (n+1 > a.length) resize();
        T b=a[(j+i)%a.length];
        a[(j+i)%a.length]=x;
        a[(j+i+c.size())%a.length]=b;
        i++;
    }   


}
```

}

```
 The array deque implementation:
  /**
 * An implementation of the List interface that allows for fast modifications
 * at both the head and tail.
 * 
 * The implementation is as a circular array.  The List item of rank i is stored
 * at a[(j+i)%a.length].  Insertions and removals at position i take 
 * O(1+min{i, size()-i}) amortized time.
 * @author morin
 *
 * @param <T> the type of objects stored in this list
 */

public class ArrayDeque<T> extends AbstractList<T> {
    /**
     * The class of elements stored in this queue
     */
    protected Factory<T> f;

/**
 * Array used to store elements
 */
protected T[] a;

/**
 * Index of next element to de-queue
 */
protected int j;

/**
 * Number of elements in the queue
 */
protected int n;

/**
 * Grow the internal array
 */
protected void resize() {
    T[] b = f.newArray(Math.max(2*n,1));
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) 
        b[k] = a[(j+k) % a.length];
    a = b;
    j = 0;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public ArrayDeque(Class<T> t) {
    f = new Factory<T>(t);
    a = f.newArray(1);
    j = 0;
    n = 0;
}

public int size() {
    return n;
}

public T get(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i > n-1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    return a[(j+i)%a.length];
}

public T set(int i, T x) {
    if (i < 0 || i > n-1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    T y = a[(j+i)%a.length];
    a[(j+i)%a.length] = x;
    return y;
}

public void add(int i, T x) {
    if (i < 0 || i > n) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    if (n+1 > a.length) resize();
    if (i < n/2) {  // shift a[0],..,a[i-1] left one position
        j = (j == 0) ? a.length - 1 : j - 1; // (j-1) mod a.length
        for (int k = 0; k <= i-1; k++)
            a[(j+k)%a.length] = a[(j+k+1)%a.length];
    } else {        // shift a[i],..,a[n-1] right one position
        for (int k = n; k > i; k--)
            a[(j+k)%a.length] = a[(j+k-1)%a.length];
    }
    a[(j+i)%a.length] = x;
    n++;
}

public T remove(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i > n - 1) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    T x = a[(j+i)%a.length];
    if (i < n/2) {  // shift a[0],..,[i-1] right one position
        for (int k = i; k > 0; k--)
            a[(j+k)%a.length] = a[(j+k-1)%a.length];
        j = (j + 1) % a.length;
    } else {        // shift a[i+1],..,a[n-1] left one position
        for (int k = i; k < n-1; k++)
            a[(j+k)%a.length] = a[(j+k+1)%a.length];
    }
    n--;
    if (3*n < a.length) resize();
    return x;
}

public void clear() {
    n = 0;
    resize();
}
}
```

Comment: that error makes no sense, can you provide some context? I dont see anything here that would say `BulkArrayDeque contains incorrect values after using addAll` is this for a unit test?

Comment: Agreed. You'll have to tell exactly how you "tested it on a server". Also, it looks to me like if you add a massive number of elements at once, you may be in trouble... `resize()` "only" doubles the size of the internal array. If you add 1000 elements to an array that's only got 100 elements in it now, what happens?

Comment: Does that mean the implementation is correct?